# MVC having same controller and action name in area folder too

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having a action method in root folder New/NewForm. The partial view NewForm will be called from New controller... I have a New folder in Area folder too but the action method NewForm is not there in the controller NewController.. but while working from root folder i am invoking a ajax call for New/Newform but it is not getting called rather the application just hangs.. when i exclude the area folder "New" it is working fine. Any solutions would be great to me now as i need to solve this quickly..

Thanking you in advance.

Thanks,
Vin

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong

The ajax call which you are trying to make from your view will depend on the location of the view.

Suppose if your view is the Root Views then the url for the ajax call will be

**url:'controller/actionmethod'  I e url:'New/NewMethod',**

If you want to make ajax call to a controller which is in an Area

For example Area name is Product

then the url will be **url:'Product/New/NewMethod'  Ie area/controller/actionmethod'**

Thanks

Comment: Yes correct. I used the same way as you mentioned but it is not working but the moment when i exclude the NEW folder from area folder it id working fine. The idea is i am maintaining the same files between the root and area folder whereas the area folder will have some changes from view side(design changes).. i am confused now why this is happening..